# sunspot solr: search for "Everything" / wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

How would one search in Sunspot solr with a wildcard?
Use * does not work, I want to return all the results for education.

Education is a collection that can exists of "All", "High", "Low", so now my idea is to remove it from the search block if its "All"

```
with(:orientation, params[:orientation])  
if params[:orientation].present? unless params[:orientation] == "all"
```

*Must be a better way?*

## Search block:

```
search = Sunspot.search Session do

      if params[:education].present?
        if params[:education] == "all"
          # Use a wildcard here
          #with(:education, *)
        end
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is actually to remove the query as you say.
It's cleaner and is quicker because the engine has one less condition to run.
So:

```
with(:orientation, params[:orientation])  
if params[:orientation].present? unless params[:orientation] == "all"
```

is indeed the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

## solution:

I finally found the problem, I had some issues in my development database where Profile was not having a Match. + some missing profile_id in the match table, after fixing those the reindex went fine.